# Tabbar Customisation in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, tabbar

I have studied about creating **`Tabbar`** in Flutter but as so far I know We can create Tabbar inside **`AppBar`** widget which is inside **`Scaffold`** widget.

But I want something like below :

[image]

**So far I have as below:**

[image]

I have created Tab screens but have to manage tab selections as above.

As you can see above, Appbar is different and tabbar is outside Appbar,
How can I manage this to customise this Tabs in Flutter? Thanks.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have the Tabbar already working, and it's in the position you want, but it's not customized as if it is different from a tabbar, right? Can you put a screenshot showing where you are now?

Comment: Sure. Edited Question, you can check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String title;

  const MyHomePage({
    Key? key,
    required this.title,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
        length: 3,
        child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            centerTitle: false,
            title: Text(
              "Facilities",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20),
            ),
            actions: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20.0),
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {},
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.search,
                      size: 26.0,
                    ),
                  )),
            ],
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            elevation: 0,
            bottom: TabBar(
                unselectedLabelColor: Colors.redAccent,
                indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
                indicator: BoxDecoration(
                    gradient: LinearGradient(
                        colors: [Colors.redAccent, Colors.orangeAccent]),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(6),
                    color: Colors.redAccent),
                tabs: [
                  Tab(
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: Text("Attraction"),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Tab(
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: Text("Events"),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Tab(
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: Text("Utils"),
                    ),
                  ),
                ]),
          ),
          body: TabBarView(children: [
            Icon(Icons.apps),
            Icon(Icons.movie),
            Icon(Icons.games),
          ]),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: How can I give the background color as lightyellow in tabbar.. you can see unselected color in tabbar. How?

Comment: wrape to tabBar, bottom: PreferredSize(
              preferredSize: _tabBar.preferredSize,
              child: Material(
                color: Colors.yellow,
                child: Theme(
                    //<-- SEE HERE
                    data: ThemeData().copyWith(splashColor: Colors.redAccent),
                    child: _tabBar // use same tabbar data here
                ),
              ),
            ),

Comment: not getting.. can you please explain in your answer

Comment: and can we decrease the size of tabbar?

Comment: check here for full details 
            https://www.flutterbeads.com/change-tab-bar-color-in-flutter/

Comment: It almost fone. but I have to remove space from left and side of Tabbar. How ?